# image API src into <img> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm starting out with jquery and json, working on a weather app using OpenWeatherMap's API. I'm trying to pass an [icon](http://www.openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) src to be displayed with an img tag. I understand something analogous has been asked before (which was my model for the code below), but I'm not seeing a change in `<img>` upon inspection.

In my view I have `<img id="icon" src="#">`, and this is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lati = position.coords.latitude;
      var longi = position.coords.longitude;
      var address = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lati +"&lon=" + longi + "&APPID=****";

      $.getJSON(address, function(json) {
        var iconSrc = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +json.weather.icon +".png";
        $('#icon img').attr('src', iconSrc);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#icon img').attr('src', iconSrc);` selection is not the correct one for your example

you are trying to select an `img` element that is a child of an element with id icon `#icon`

select only with the id

```
$('#icon').attr('src', iconSrc);
```

Remember id's should be unique, so if you have multiple img tags to populate use classes